# After update called twice but fetching the old value

Tags: apex, approval-process, apex-managed-sharing

I have created 2 Approval process.

I have an afterupdate trigger. Once the record enters Approval process, the status becomes "In Approvals".Record will move to the second approval process after the approval of first approval process. Once the second approval process completes, iam updating the status in the trigger to "Initials obtained".

I have another afterupdate trigger used for apex sharing. This will give access to the users based on status.

The issue is once both Approval process is complete and status changes to Initials obtained, Iam still recieving the Sharing which has been put for In Approvals status.

When i see the debug logs, i see that the Afterupdate trigger called for Apex sharing was called 2 times one after other. First time the sharing was calculated correctly with Initials obtained but in the next log, it is taking the sharing for In Approvals.

Users are reporting access issues. Can you please help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I doubt that other people will have hit your problem (as it is pretty specific), so I think you will need to post your trigger to get useful comment.

Comment: Your first trigger will likely fire 2x because of workflow. This could also cause the 2nd trigger to fire again. The issue is likely related to how you've set up the conditions for the 2nd trigger to fire. You'll need to post your code if we're to help you.